# modify Windows Firewall with command prompt

Tags: batch-file, windows-firewall

using Command Prompt to modify Windows Firewall

can i allow Domain/Public/Private checkmarks all in the same row (like i can do by manually clicking)?

what i have so far makes 3 entries, one checkmark for each type:

> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="MyApp" dir=in action=allow program="C:\MyApp.exe" enable=yes profile=domain
>
> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="MyApp" dir=in action=allow program="C:\MyApp.exe" enable=yes profile=public
>
> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="MyApp" dir=in action=allow program="C:\MyApp.exe" enable=yes profile=private

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you can do to solve it:

```
profile=Private and/or public and/or domain
(To add rule in more than one profile use “,” E.g.: profile=private, domain )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "fcmd=netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="MyApp" dir=in action=allow program="C:\MyApp.exe" enable=yes profile="
for %a in (domain public private) do (
    echo %fcmd%%a
```

If you want to run it in batch file, just double the %'s for %a to %%a.
Remove the Echo when you test for acceptable output.

And just to tidy things up a bit:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set fcmd=netsh advfirewall firewall add rule ^
 name="MyApp" dir=in action=allow program="C:\MyApp.exe" ^
 enable=yes profile=
for %a in (domain public private) do (
    echo %fcmd%%a
)
```